# Pass ampersand multiple in url for php

Tags: php, pdo, phpmyadmin

I would like to be able to pass an "&" which I collect from a data account but the string remains empty:

Fail: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVYL5.jpg
But those that do not contain "&" but contain characters with and "ñ" if they work

My code for url:

```
<td>
<a href="?action=editar&id=<?php echo $r->acronimo; ?>"><img src="icon_editthis.png" width="30px" height="30px"/></a>
<td>
<a href="?action=eliminar&acronimo=<?php echo $r->acronimo; ?>"><img src="delete.png" width="30px" height="30px"/></a>
</td>
```

I try this:

```
<a href="?action=editar&id=<?php echo urldecode($r)->acronimo; ?>"><img src="icon_editthis.png" width="30px" height="30px"/></a>
```

But it does not work
Thx for your help!

Comment: What does `$r->acronimo` contain? And the use of `urldecode()` is wrong - it should be `urldecode($r->acronimo)`, not `urldecode($r)->acronimo` - the latter should return an error (you should always turn errors on when developing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using URL decode, I think you should be using URL *encode*.

Give this a try:

```
<td>
    <a href="?action=editar&id=<?php echo urlencode($r->acronimo); ?>"><img src="icon_editthis.png" width="30px" height="30px"/></a>
</td>
<td>
    <a href="?action=eliminar&acronimo=<?php echo urlencode($r->acronimo); ?>"><img src="delete.png" width="30px" height="30px"/></a>
</td>
```

According to the PHP documentation for `urlencode()`:

> This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page.

The idea is that the ampersand has a semantic meaning in a url - in separates parameters in query strings. You must encode your parameter values to ensure these kinds of special characters are considered part of the parameter value and are not be parsed.

Documentation is available here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Please note that I also fixed a missing `</td>`.

Comment: You are a genious !!!Just need to change the "fetch" of the PDO, in addition to what you told me--------- $r = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $alm = new Categoria();

            $alm->__SET('acronimo', $r["acronimo"]);
            $alm->__SET('categoria', $r["categoria"]);


--- Now it works perfect

Comment: Happy to be of help! If this answer helped, please remember to mark it as the correct answer and up-vote. Helps us answerers a lot.

Comment: I get this "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." sorry but i mark as the correct answer!!